# Javascript select an option by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following select dropdown that occurs when a user clicks an item:

```
        $(this).html($("<select/>", {
          class: 'sel',
        }).append($("<option/>", { text: "WIP" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "C" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "A" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "AR" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "NS" }))
        );
```

In addition, I have a variable called `status` that is defined that as either "WIP", "C", "A", "AR", or "NS".

```
status = trim(($(this).text()));
```

I want to make it such that when I click the `select` dropdown, the `option == status` will be selected. For example:

```
status = "WIP"
<select class="sel">
     <option selected="selected">WIP</option>
     <option>C</option>
     ...
</select>
```

Comment: can you provide some more information? When is the `status` variable assigned? Can it change due to user interaction, and if so, should the dropdown change as well?

Comment: It would help if you made a jsfiddle

Comment: Why is the drop down necessary if the status is set when a user clicks an item?

Comment: @DavidJohnson my guess is he's creating an 'edit-in-place' type of element. It displays text; but when the user clicks it, the text is replaced by a select menu, with the appropriate option selected by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand the question, you want to set a default `option` so that *before* the user clicks there'll be an option selected.

Here's how you would do that:

```
var status = "WIP";

$("<select/>", {
    class: 'sel',
})
.append( $("<option/>", { text: "WIP" }) )
.append( $("<option/>", { text: "C" }) )
.append( $("<option/>", { text: "A" }) )
.append( $("<option/>", { text: "AR" }) )
.append( $("<option/>", { text: "NS" }) )
.val( status )
.appendTo(this);
```

Note that the whole `select` element should be built before `append`ing it to the DOM. This is *much* better for performance, since any interaction with the DOM is very expensive.

Answer (score 2):

You could also reduce the repetition of your code if you put your option text values in an array:

```
var options = ['WIP','C','A','AR','NS'];
var menu = $('<select>',{class:'sel'});

$.each(options,function(i,text){
    menu.append($('<option>',{text:text}));
});

menu.val(status).appendTo(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, to get the stored value to be selected as the user clicks on the select.

Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/TRCWh/

code

```
<div id = "hello"></div>

var select = "A";
$('#hello').html($("<select/>", {
          class: 'sel',
        }).append($("<option/>", { text: "WIP" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "C" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "A" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "AR" }))
          .append($("<option/>", { text: "NS" }))
                );

$(document).on("click",".sel",function(){
    $(this).val(select);
})
```

Note: I have ignored the accepted coding practice(as some might say) for a while. just for the sake of giving an quick fix answer to your problem :)